# Unsemantic CSS Framework and fluid images

Tags: css, image, fluid-layout, css-frameworks, unsemantic-css

Recently I started messing around with [Unsemantic](http://unsemantic.com/) css framework, but it's seems that using grids and flexible images css markup doesn't work together. Is there a way for solving this problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Can you give us some code with a specific example and explanation of the problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forgot to update, I solved this problem. I was using nested grids, and so forgot to add grid class to one of them (silly me).

```
<section id="blank-page-content" class="grid-100 grid-parent">      
        <article class="grid-100 grid-parent blank-page-post">

            <figure class="blank-page-post-thumbanil grid-20 grid-parent">
                <img src="" alt="ph-image"/>
            </figure>

            <section class="blank-page-post-content grid-80 grid-parent">
            </section>

        </article>
</section>
```

I was missing class="grid-100 grid-parent" on the top level section element.